# Sending html in JSON, R

Tags: html, json, r, xml, post

I have an html output in the form of a table and I want to send that with my JSON eventually via a POST for an api.

I have removed tags and troubleshot it but doesnt work. Is there a specific library that I can use in R to achieve this parsing?

I am using simple paste() to parse that html page and insert it into JSON's 'value'.

I first save my data.frame(list) as html then I try to parse it.

```
mydoc = bsdoc( title = 'xxx' )
mydoc=  addFlexTable( mydoc, flextable = output_as_flex)
mydoc = addParagraph( mydoc, value = "<br>")
writeDoc(mydoc,file ="C://yyy.html")
tree=htmlTreeParse("C://yyy.html")
```

Here I follow the Confluence Rest Api's format to form this string for JSON. Data has to be passed(I am passing a variable in paste) as html where 'h_h'

```
data <- paste(sep='','{"type":"page","title":', 
              '"xxx",', 
              '"ancestors":[{"id":',123123,'}],"space":{"key":"','xxx','"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"',h_h,'","representation":"storage"}}}')


httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer=FALSE))
URL <- "xxx/rest/api/content"
response = POST(URL, authenticate("xx", "xx"), body = data, verbose(),add_headers('Content-Type' = 'application/json;charset=utf-8','Cache-Control'='no-cache'))
response
http_status(response)
warn_for_status(response) 
stop_for_status(response)
```

I want to upload that html table formed as output_as_flex to the api and eventually to the confluence page.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want actual help you should provide example data and a desired outcome

Comment: @SymbolixAU done. thanks. I have tried using toJson but I need to parse it as html. Maybe now that i have provided snippets you can help me better.